# ASP.Net GridView1_RowDataBound not firing

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

I'm trying to set up some conditional formatting in a GridView to highlight rows based on a date, but I can't even get the basic RowDataBound to fire on a line of test code.

```
     protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if row is data row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[4].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Crimson;
    }
}
```

That does nothing at all.  No errors and no colored cells or rows.

Here is all my GridView1 markup:

```
            Department:  
        <asp:DropDownList ID="Department" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Department_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Communications</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Employer Services</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Executive</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Fiscal</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Human Resources</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Information Technology</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Legal</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Operations</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Quality Assurance</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>


        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ContractID" DataSourceID="ContractsDataSource" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Size="Small" EditRowStyle-BackColor="#FFCCCC" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="False" CausesValidation="False" UpdateText="Save" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContractID" HeaderText="ContractID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ContractID" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Company" HeaderText="Contract / Agreement" SortExpression="Company" >
                <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Active">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Active") %>' Width="110px" CausesValidation="False">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Active" Text="Active" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Not active" Text="Not active" />
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Active") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ExpirationDate" HeaderText="Expiration Date" SortExpression="ExpirationDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="False" ApplyFormatInEditMode="True" >
                <ControlStyle Width="85px" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department" >
                <ControlStyle Width="200px" />
                <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactPerson" HeaderText="Primary Contact" SortExpression="ContactPerson" >
                <ControlStyle Width="120px" />
                <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="email01" HeaderText="email 1" SortExpression="email01" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="email02" HeaderText="email 2" SortExpression="email02" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="email03" HeaderText="email 3" SortExpression="email03" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="email04" HeaderText="email 4" SortExpression="email04" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="email05" HeaderText="email 5" SortExpression="email05" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Renewal Notes" SortExpression="Notes">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Notes") %>' MaxLength="1000" Rows="3" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Notes") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ControlStyle Width="275px" />
                    <HeaderStyle Width="275px" />
                    <ItemStyle Width="275px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateEntered" HeaderText="Date Entered" SortExpression="DateEntered" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="False" ApplyFormatInEditMode="True" >
                <ControlStyle Width="85px" />
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateUpdated" HeaderText="Date Updated" SortExpression="DateUpdated" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="False" Visible="False" ApplyFormatInEditMode="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdatedBy" HeaderText="Updated By" SortExpression="UpdatedBy" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RenewalAmount" DataFormatString="{0:c}" HeaderText="Renewal Amount" HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="RenewalAmount">
                <ControlStyle Width="110px" />
                <HeaderStyle Width="110px" />
                <ItemStyle Width="110px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ReferenceNumber" HeaderText="Reference Number (PO/Contract/Agreement)" SortExpression="ReferenceNumber">
                <ControlStyle Width="200px" />
                <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
                </asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>

            <%--<EmptyDataTemplate>
                <label id="no_data" runat="server">No contracts to display for the selected department.</label>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <EmptyDataRowStyle ForeColor="Blue"/>--%>

            <EditRowStyle CssClass="GridViewEditRow" BackColor="#ffcccc"  />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ContractsDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ContractsConnectionString %>" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Contracts] WHERE [ContractID] = @ContractID" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Contracts(Company, Active, ExpirationDate, Department, ContactPerson, email01, email02, email03, email04, email05, Notes, DateEntered, DateUpdated, UpdatedBy, RenewalAmount, ReferenceNumber) VALUES (@Company, @Active, @ExpirationDate, @Department, @ContactPerson, @email01, @email02, @email03, @email04, @email05, @Notes, @DateEntered, @DateUpdated, @UpdatedBy, @RenewalAmount, @ReferenceNumber)" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT ContractID, Company, Active, ExpirationDate, Department, ContactPerson, email01, email02, email03, email04, email05, Notes, DateEntered, DateUpdated, UpdatedBy, RenewalAmount, ReferenceNumber FROM Contracts WHERE (Department = @Department AND Active LIKE @Active + '%') ORDER BY Company" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE Contracts SET Company = @Company, Active = @Active, ExpirationDate = @ExpirationDate, Department = @Department, ContactPerson = @ContactPerson, email01 = @email01, email02 = @email02, email03 = @email03, email04 = @email04, email05 = @email05, Notes = @Notes, DateEntered = @DateEntered, DateUpdated = @DateUpdated, UpdatedBy = @UpdatedBy, RenewalAmount = @RenewalAmount, ReferenceNumber = @ReferenceNumber WHERE (ContractID = @ContractID)">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContractID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Company" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Active" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="ExpirationDate" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Department" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContactPerson" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email01" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email02" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email03" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email04" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email05" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DateEntered" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DateUpdated" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="UpdatedBy" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RenewalAmount" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ReferenceNumber" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Department" Name="Department" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Active" Name="Active" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" DefaultValue="%" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Company" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Active" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="ExpirationDate" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Department" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContactPerson" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email01" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email02" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email03" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email04" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email05" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DateEntered" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DateUpdated" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="UpdatedBy" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RenewalAmount" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ReferenceNumber" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ContractID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I've done this exact same thing on other pages and it worked fine.  I just compared this to a working page and can find no differences, other than maybe the "Department" filter I have on this one.

Comment: You havent registered the event handler. `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ...`

Comment: Oh, darn!  I thought that was automatic.  Hahaha  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Tim Schmelter actually answered in a comment.  I had forgotten to register the RowDataBound event handler in the GridView markup.